# Laravel 5.7 Get data from Pivot Table

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table

I'm trying to get data from my pivot table.

clients table:

```
---|------
id | name
---|------
1  | John
---|------
2  | Steve
```

orders table:

```
---|------
id | description
---|------
1  | Mac
---|------
2  | Keyboard
---|------
3  | Printer
```

client_order (pivot)table:

```
    id | client_id | order_id
    ---|-----------|------
    1  | 1           1
    ---|-----------|------
    2  | 1         | 2
    ---|-----------|------
    3  | 2         | 3
```

Client.php

```
 public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order','client_order');
}
```

Order.php

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Client','client_order');
}
```

Now, how can I retrieve data from pivot table? For example:

```
John | Mac, Keyboard (2 orders)
Steve| Printer (1 orders)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For client:

```
$client = Client::find(1); //or anyway you create the client
$client->orders; //it gives you a collection that you can get data 
in a foreach loop
//for example
foreach($client->orders as $order){
    echo $order->description;
}
```

For order:

```
$order = Order::find(1); //or anyway you create order
$order->clients; //it gives you a collection too
//for example
foreach($order->clients as $client){
    echo $client->name;
}
```

This is for your new comment. First you select your users and then in a loop you can get the orders:

```
$clients = Client::all();
foreach($clients as $client){
    echo $client->name." | ";
    foreach($client->orders as $order){
        echo $order->description;
    }
    echo "(".count($client->orders)." orders)";
}
```

Comment: It's Okay about displaying data in their own queries, but how to get data in a single query for these two tables together because I need to display in a single table in order to get number of orders for each clients. for example:
John | Mac, Keyboard (2 orders)
Steve| Printer (1 order)

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using the relations as @Rouhollah Mazarei said, but you can also use the own pivot table to retrieve this information:

```
$clientsOrders = DB::table('client_order')->where('client_id', $clientId)->count()->get();
```

This will return to you how many orders this client made, you just need to inform his id.